# Recursively check array for new elements and trigger action

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, file

I am running a script that generates constantly files every 60 seconds, which I then store in an array:

```
my_files = [file1, file2, ..., filen]
```

As this array keeps growing dynamically, I need to recursively keep checking on this for new files. Every time there are new files, I need to add them to a "queue" and wait for them to be processed by calling other functions.

What is the best way to do that? I have looked into watchdog but it seems very complex for what I need. I have also tried using the following class, which will allow me to recursively check my folder but then I am not able to iterate over the files that "fetches" because it is not a `list`:

```
class RepeatedTimer(object):

    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer = None
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.next_call = time.time()
        self.start()

     def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

     def start(self):
         if not self.is_running:
             self.next_call += self.interval
             self._timer = threading.Timer(self.next_call - time.time(), self._run)
             self._timer.start()
             self.is_running = True

     def stop(self):
         self._timer.cancel()
         self.is_running = False
```

The following won't work, therefore I can't access the files:

```
my_files = [RepeatedTimer(30, pick_testing_files)]

while True:
    if len(my_files) > 0:
        files_to_be_processed = my_files.pop()
        threading.Thread(target=test, args=(files_to_be_processed)).start()
```

Comment: `my_files` is called a `list` in Python, not an array, by-the-way. What exactly are the types of `file1, file2, ..., filen`? Why does the checking need to be recursive?

Comment: @martineau they are pcap files, that are generated every 60 seconds. It doesn’t have to be recursively, but I need to check the folders every x minutes to fetch the newly created files.

Comment: Do you mean they are file _names_? Python has a built-in type by that name is why I ask.

Comment: Yes, like: my_files = [ file1.pcap, file2.pcap, etc.]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work (as far as my own limited testing indicates at least). I added a `threading.Lock` to protect the shared resource `my_files` from concurrent access.

```
import random
import string
import threading
import time


class RepeatedTimer:
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer = None
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.next_call = time.time()
        self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.next_call += self.interval
            self._timer = threading.Timer(self.next_call - time.time(), self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False


def pick_testing_files(filenames, lock):
    newfiles = []
    with lock:
        while True:
            try:
                filename = filenames.pop()
            except IndexError:  # List is empty.
                break
            newfiles.append(filename)

    print('files retrieved:', newfiles)

def random_filename():
    letters = []
    for _ in range(random.randint(4, 8)):
        letters.append(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase))
    return ''.join(letters)


my_files = []
filelist_lock = threading.Lock()

watcher = RepeatedTimer(5, pick_testing_files, my_files, filelist_lock)
#watcher.start()  # Not needed because RepeatedTimer's start themselves.

for _ in range(30):  # Run test for 30 seconds.
    # Add some filenames to my_files list.
    with filelist_lock:
        for _ in range(random.randint(1, 4)):  # Generate some filenames.
            my_files.append(random_filename())
    print('new files added')
    time.sleep(1)  # Wait a little before adding more filenames.

watcher.cancel()
```